# How can I make the card component work with react-split-pane component?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, stackblitz, splitpane, card

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dkmajd?file=src%2FTest1.js) is my code.

My problem is, how can I use the card component to fill the first pane of the SplitPane without using h-100 class?

It is because when I use h-100 class for the Card component, it spoils the layout when the users click on the input box on the mobile platform.

I tried to use the "flex-grow-1" class to solve the problem, however, it does not work.

Besides that, I am not sure whether the react-split-pane its own handling method for the orientation change event. If so, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation using `flex-grow-1` will not work because if you inspect the elements, the parent of the `Card` component is an additional `div` element generated by the `SplitPane` and is not a `flex` container.

You can still use `h-100` but in order to solve the layout issues on "small window.innerHeight" devices (such as the scenario you described like opening the virtual keyboard on a mobile devices), you simply need to make tweaks in your condition statements to assess whether the `SplitPane` should switch `split` prop of `horizontal` or `vertical`

In my example below you can see that I factor in a "minimum width" for the left pane to consider the `width` of the input field on your StackBlitz example code which is set to `182px` as I reviewed.

```
this.setOrientation = () => {

  let leftPanelMinWidth = 182;

  if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth - leftPanelMinWidth) {
    this.setState({ splitDirection: "horizontal" });
  } else {
    this.setState({ splitDirection: "vertical" });
  }
}
```

I imagine you can implement the same in logic when the component mounts.

Comment: Finally, I give up to use Splitpane